# What to do when it says "unable to locate package" policykit

Tags: 11.10, package-management, policykit

I'm following a tutorial that says I need to run `sudo apt-get update` and then install a whole bunch of packages. All of them work, except `policykit`. It gives me `Unable to locate package policykit`. Is there something I need to do to help ubuntu find it. I'm new to ubuntu so not sure how this works, or if I need to put the ubuntu installation CD for this to work or what.

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general suggestion:

Whenever you are in such situation, try the following command to locate the package:

```
apt-cache search packagename
```

And after that try to install the packgae which reads as packagename-dev or libpackage name

```
sudo apt-get install packagename-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The package you are looking for is installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install policykit-1
```

You can search for packages using:

```
apt-cache search policykit
```